# select sum statement

Tags: sql

I created this select statement I will convert to a view. I need help with this. I need to be able to add the total of Minority that = Yes and No show total on report pages.

```
select
    ps.BidPackage_ID,
    ps.Project_ID,
    SUM (case ps.Minority when 'Yes' then 1 else 0 end) MinorityTotal,
    SUM (case ps.Gender when 'Female' then 1 else 0 end) FemaleTotal,
    SUM(case ps.Cleveland_Resident when 1 then 1 else 0 end) ClevelandResidents,
    ps.SubContractor
from
    PersonnelSummary ps
group by
    ps.BidPackage_ID,
    ps.Project_ID,
    ps.SubContractor
```

Comment: SQL Server? Or other? And what version?

Comment: I'm not clear on exactly what it is that you're trying to get. Can you include some sample data and expected output or try explaining it in another way?

Answer (score 1):

You nearly have it:

```
...
SUM (case ps.Minority when 'Yes' then 1 else 0 end) AS MinorityYes,
SUM (case ps.Minority when 'No' then 1 else 0 end) AS MinorityNo,
COUNT(*) AS Total,
...
```

With the `Total` I'm assuming that every row should be counted. This is what you want if:

- The only values that exist in the column are 'Yes' and 'No' *or*
- Values different from 'Yes' and 'No' should also be counted in the total.

Comment: So 'MinorityTotal' is really 'Total'?

Answer (score 0):

You're forcing us to guess what you want.  You have a count of the people who said that they were in a minority; do you want a count of the people who said No?  Or do you want a count of the number who said 'either "Yes" or "No"' and excluding those who gave 'decline to say' or simply no answer at all?

```
select
    ps.BidPackage_ID,
    ps.Project_ID,
    SUM (case ps.Minority when 'Yes' then 1 else 0 end) MinorityTotalYes,
    SUM (case ps.Minority when 'No'  then 1 else 0 end) MinorityTotalNo,
    SUM (case ps.Minority when 'Yes' then 1 when 'No' then 1 else 0 end) 
    AS StatedMinorityTotal,
    SUM (case ps.Gender when 'Female' then 1 else 0 end) FemaleTotal,
    SUM(case ps.Cleveland_Resident when 1 then 1 else 0 end) ClevelandResidents,
    ps.SubContractor
from
    PersonnelSummary ps
group by
    ps.BidPackage_ID,
    ps.Project_ID,
    ps.SubContractor
```